# Can the completion of one async call be sequenced before the start of another using useEffect?

Tags: react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to use `useEffect` in my React app but also refactor things more modularly.  Shown below is the heart of actual working code.  It resides in a Context Provider file and does the following:
1. Calls AWS Amplify to get the latest Auth Access Token.
2. Uses this token, in the form of an `Authorization` header, when an Axios GET call is made to an API Endpoint.

This works fine but I thought it would make more sense to move Step #1 into its own `useEffect` construct above.  Furthermore, in doing so, I could then also store the header object as its own Context property, which the GET call could then reference.

Unfortunately, I can now see from console log statements that when the GET call starts, the Auth Access Token has not yet been retrieved.  So the refactoring attempt fails.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const config = {
        headers: { "Authorization":  
          await Auth.currentSession()
            .then(data => {
              return data.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
            })
            .catch(error => {
              alert('Error getting authorization token: '.concat(error))
            })
          }};

      await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/some_path', config)
        .then(response => {
          // Process the retrieved data and populate in a Context property

        })
        .catch(error => {
          alert('Error getting data from endpoint: '.concat(error));
        });
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [myContextObject.some_data]);
```

Is there a way of refactoring my code into two `useEffect` instances such that the first one will complete before the second one starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hold the config object in a state. This way you can separate both fetch calls and trigger the second one once the first one finished:

```
const MyComponent = props => {
    const myContextObject = useContext(myContext);
    const [config, setConfig] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: await Auth.currentSession()
                        .then(data => {
                            return data.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            alert("Error getting authorization token: ".concat(error));
                        })
                }
            };

            setConfig(config);
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [myContextObject.some_data]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!config) {
            return;
        }

        const fetchData = async () => {
            await axios
                .get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/some_path", config)
                .then(response => {
                    // Process the retrieved data and populate in a Context property
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    alert("Error getting data from endpoint: ".concat(error));
                });
        };

        fetchData();
        // This should work for the first call (not tested) as it goes from null to object.
        // If you need subsequent changes then youll have to track some property
        // of the object or similar
    }, [config]);

    return null;
};
```